# Does Task objects internally contain a collection of ContinueWith tasks?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm reading a book which says:

> Task objects internally contain a collection of ContinueWith tasks.
> So you can actually call ContinueWith several times using a single Task object. When the task
> completes, all the ContinueWith tasks will be queued to the thread pool.

so I try to check the source code of Task https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,146

I didn't find any private field that looks like a collection of ContinueWith tasks.

So my question is , does Task objects internally contain a collection of ContinueWith tasks?

And if it does,  let's say we have the following code:

```
Task<Int32> t = Task.Run(() => Sum(10000));

Task a = t.ContinueWith(task => Console.WriteLine("The sum is: " + task.Result),
 TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);

Task b = t.ContinueWith(task => Console.WriteLine("Sum threw: " + task.Exception.InnerException),
 TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

if (a == b) {
   ... // false
{
```

Since calling `ContinueWith` just add an item to a collection, then `a` and `b` should point to the same Task object, but `a == b` return false?

Comment: *Since calling ContinueWith just add an item to a collection, then a and b should point to the same Task object* I don't follow your reasoning here. Task `a` is a task that will be marked as complete when the first `WriteLine` statement finishes. Task `b` is a task that will be marked as complete when the second `WriteLine` statement finishes. Both of them require `t` to be complete before starting.  But `a` and `b` are clearly different tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could say the answer is yes and no.   The Task class utilizes Interlocked in order to keep up with continuations.

You can see the method for adding a continuation named AddTaskContinuationComplex(object tc, bool addBeforeOthers) at line 4727.  Within this method the continuation is added to a list and then passed to Interlocked.

```
            // Construct a new TaskContinuation list
            List<object> newList = new List<object>();

            // Add in the old single value
            newList.Add(oldValue);

            // Now CAS in the new list
            Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref m_continuationObject, newList, oldValue);
```

Now if you take a look at the FinishContinuations (line 3595) method you can see

```
        // Atomically store the fact that this task is completing.  From this point on, the adding of continuations will
        // result in the continuations being run/launched directly rather than being added to the continuation list.
        object continuationObject = Interlocked.Exchange(ref m_continuationObject, s_taskCompletionSentinel);
        TplEtwProvider.Log.RunningContinuation(Id, continuationObject);
```

Here the current task is being marked as completed and the next task is being obtained from Interlocked.

Now if you go to the [Interlocked class](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/interlocked.cs,8792520ddc6dadcb) and examine it, you can see that while it isn't necessarily a collection itself it keeps up with and maintains continuations in a thread-safe manner.

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph: Interlocked does not manage collections and doesn’t have anything to do with collections. Interlocked.CompareExchange roughly does a thread-safe assignment.